# Detectar que se pulsó el botón izquierdo/secundario

Tags: c#, .net

El ratón tiene diferentes eventos, por ejemplo:

- MOUSEDOWN: el botón está abajo
- MOUSEUP: el botón está arriba
- etc.

Necesito detectar esos **eventos del click izquierdo del mouse**, he revisado la mayoría de los enlaces en lo que hablan de keylogger y ganchos de bajo nivel, pero esos solo detectan (MOUSEDOWN) cuando el botón está abajo, y yo necesito detectar tambien (MOUSEUP) cuando el botón está arriba.

Debo hacerlo en el lenguaje C#, quizás utilizando una importación de libreria de windows mediante pinvoke. Pero no sé cómo. Esto es lo que quiero hacer:

```
// MOUSEDOWN detectado.
//   hacer algo...

// MOUSEUP detectado.
//   hacer otra cosa...
```

La idea es hacer algo mientras el click izquierdo está presionado. Y luego hacer otra cosa cuando se suelta el click izquierdo.

No tengo un código específico para mostrar, modifiqué los códigos que encontré en StackOverflow. Hay varios que hablan de `Keylogger` y funcionan muy bien en detectar las pulsaciones de los click de mouse, pero solo detectan (MOUSEDOWN) y no logro detectar (MOUSEUP) cuando el botón está arriba.

¿Cómo puedo detectar que es el botón izquierdo (o secundario) el que se ha pulsado?

Comment: Saludos. Te falto incluir el código que llevas e indicar cual es el problema que tienes; lo **correcto** es incluir esas funcionalidades en tu aplicación que entregas/instalas para el Cliente/Usuario final; así controlas bien y en cada evento lo manejas como corresponde. (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keylogger)

Comment: No tengo un codigo especifico para mostrar, modifico los codigos que encuentro en stackoverflow, hay varios que hablan de Keylogger y funcionan muy bien en detectar las pulsaciones de los click de mouse, pero solo detectan (MOUSEDOWN), no logro detectar (MOUSEUP) cuando el boton esta arriba. PD: Es para usar en mi propio pc.

Comment: @ezer2020 comparte el código que tienes con el que consigues leer el mousedown, quizás alguien pueda ayudarte con el mouseup basándose en lo que estés usando.

Comment: Disculpa, en este momento no tengo ninguno para mostrar, hare alguno de ejemplo para mostrar, ya que con este tema en especifico, no tengo nada funcional, solo hago pruebas y luego los borro, hasta conseguir algo que funcione, igual de todos modos me parece que en c# nose puede hacer lo que pretendo, en otro hilo habia preguntado algo parecido y publique un codigo de ejemplo, pero no hubo respuestas. E mirado en otros foros sobre preguntas muy parecidas a la mia pero tampoco consiguieron respuestas, quizas en c# no se pueda hacer.